# How can I restore my wifi services on Ubuntu 23.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 23.10

There are other, similar, questions, but either there was no resolution or the scenario did not replicate mine.

I've been running Ubuntu for a number of years.  Indeed, I was happy with 23.04 as it solved some pertinent issues.  I upgraded to 23.10 about 2 weeks ago and, until now, have been quite happy.

My problem is that one day (3 days ago, in fact) upon logging in, my wifi connection keeps timing out.  I have a hotspot, a router, and xfinity.  It won't connect to any of them.  I've booted up from my install usb drive in order to post this.  That last fact lets me know it's not the hardware since it works under a different scenario.

Exploring other questions, I understand that certain commands need to be run in order for others to help resolve the issue.

I present the results below (each command is highlighted)...
I've also run the wireless-info that has been suggested.  But I don't think I can post it here due to its length.

So, my system is IdeaPad 3, running Ubuntu 23.10, with a realtek device.  I will appreciate if anyone can help me resolve my problem.

---

### lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net:

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b852]

- Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:4853]
- Kernel driver in use: rtw89_8852be
- Kernel modules: rtw89_8852be

---

### lsmod |grep cfg:

- snd_intel_dspcfg       32768  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof
- snd_intel_sdw_acpi     16384  1 snd_intel_dspcfg
- cfg80211             1314816  3 rtw89_8852b,rtw89_core,mac80211

---

### lsusb:

- Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
- Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0bda:4853 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
- Bus 003 Device 003: ID 27c6:550a Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. FingerPrint
- Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
- Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
- Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0781:5588 SanDisk Corp. Extreme Pro
- Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd
- Bus 002 Device 002: ID 045b:0210 Hitachi, Ltd
- Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
- Bus 001 Device 003: ID 174f:2465 Syntek Integrated Camera
- Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1c4f:0016 SiGma Micro USB Keyboard
- Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd
- Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045b:0209 Hitachi, Ltd
- Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

---

### sudo rfkill list:

0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN

- Soft blocked: no
- Hard blocked: no

1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth

- Soft blocked: yes
- Hard blocked: no

2: hci0: Bluetooth

- Soft blocked: yes
- Hard blocked: no

3: phy0: Wireless LAN

- Soft blocked: no
- Hard blocked: no

[This is URL](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/cYbzmv5y2F/) to pastebin containing the wireless-info results.

Comment: "I've also run the wireless-info that has been suggested. But I don't think I can post it here due to its length." Please post it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: done. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Are you attempting to connect to 'Jennings'?

Comment: I go back and forth between Jennins and xfinitywifi.  Having spent so much non-prioductive time on this over the past 3 days, I decided to just re-install the OS.  Now all is working peacefully.